# How to place multiple objects using ARCore

Tags: arcore

I want to make an ARCore app where you can select what you want to place. Does anyone know how to do this

Comment: What you tried so far?

Comment: Nothing yet
For unity

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using the default example, you can change the line:

```
public GameObject m_andyAndroidPrefab;
```

to the line:

```
public List<GameObject> m_Prefabs;
```

In your Update() method, change the existing Instantiate invocation with this:

```
var object = Instantiate(m_Prefabs[m_currentObjectIndex], 
                    hit.Point, Quaternion.identity, anchor.transform);
```

m_currentObjectIndex is an integer that holds the current index of the desired prefab to create. You will need to update this field when the user selects an object in your menu, for example.